# Employee systerm oo

Tags: oop

Question:I have Manager interface with managePeople method.
Waiter interface with takeOrder Method.
Dan is Waiter and Manager,Tom is only Waiter.
So in the question Dan implements both of them.
Tom implements only Waiter.What is neede to be in the main -> dan.takeOrder()/tom.managePeople()/tom.takeOrder() how do you fix this design?

so I have made Interface for Manaageable Way and anyone can add strategy for impl.
Another TakingOrder interface and it's impl so they will be 2 diffrenet implenations.(for tom and dan)
Now Waiter class will include member of TakingOrder impl.
and the same for ManageableWay.
Waiter and Manager extends User
Now  I create worker that includes Listas member.But now if you want to user new Worker().takeOrder/managePeople I should use instance of and this becomes a mess

Comment: Can you show any code?

Answer (score 0):

Tom cannot `managePeople()` because he doesn't implement Manager.
 on the other hand, Tom and Dan can `Takeorder()` because they both implement Waiter.

You can use the inheritance and say that any manager can also function as a waiter If necessary.

```
interface Manager extends Waiter
```